# Array of List, get the same character of each list, how?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, items

I am new to C Sharp. I have following code

```
List<string>[] a = new List<string>[3];

for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    a[i] = new List<string>();
}

a[0].Add("a");
a[0].Add("c");

a[1].Add("a");
a[1].Add("d");

a[2].Add("a");
a[2].Add("f");
```

I want to output all a's of the Array of List[] a. How do I get all the a's out of the different Lists?

Comment: What have you tried in order to find all those nested `a`? About the *Beside that* - each SO question should have only a single question so when people look for solutions to there answers it is clear what the question is about

Comment: other than your initial code would not compile - a few bits are missing, much as you try and do things by a for loop to put things in the lists, you can use a for (or foreach) loop to get them out - how far have you got?

Comment: You know how to iterate through array using for loop. Do the same iteration twice - iterate through array, then inside iterate through list items. If list item meets condition (is equal to "a") then output it to console.

Comment: This `a.SelectMany(x => x).Where(x => x == "a")` will give you an `IEnumerable` which will resut in 3 `a`?

Comment: Sorry for the second question. I will consider the advices given!

Comment: [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2) go there and see methods from left navigation

Comment: Well, I hope you caught my answer to your now edited away second part of your question before I got dinged for answering a question that had disappeared.  The answer looked like: `List<string>[] _myArray = 
{
new List<string>{"a", "c" },
new List<string>{"a", "d" },
new List<string>{"a", "f" },
};`

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks! Searched for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the "a"'s with something like:

```
var b = a.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y == "a"));
```

Test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TH4Vuz

You can play with that as a stating point if you need to get the indexes, for example

Answer (score 0):

if you are new and don't know LINQ yet try this

```
            foreach(var collection in a)
            {
                foreach(var letter in collection)
                {
                    if (letter == "a")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(letter);
                    }
                }
            }
```